# Python - pandas: Rollingmean command is not working

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, rolling-average

```
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data={'user': [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2], 'usage': 
[12,18,76,32,43,45,19,42,9,10]})
dataframe['mean'] = dataframe.groupby('user'['usage'].apply(pd.rolling_mean, 2))
```

Why this code is not working?

i am getting an error of rolling mean attribute is not found in pandas

Comment: what's the definition of pd variable? it probably does not have method rolling_mean defined

Comment: You have a syntax error (missing parenthesis) in your code. Can you please fix it first, and include the error message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `groupby` with `rolling`, [`docs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#groupby-syntax-with-window-and-resample-operations):

```
dataframe['mean'] = (dataframe.groupby('user')['usage']
                              .rolling(2)
                              .mean()
                              .reset_index(level=0, drop=True))
print (dataframe)
   user  usage  mean
0     1     12   NaN
1     1     18  15.0
2     1     76  47.0
3     1     32  54.0
4     1     43  37.5
5     2     45   NaN
6     2     19  32.0
7     2     42  30.5
8     2      9  25.5
9     2     10   9.5
```